# WCF Exception: Cannot add to list of known types

Tags: wcf, invalidoperationexception, known-types

Good Day Everyone...

I’m getting an unexpected WCF error complaining of “Known Types” which are similarly named, but in different name-spaces (see error below).

*...please keep in mind I'm still experimenting with all this.*

Also…

I already understand the nature of regular web-services FORCES you to flatten your object hierarchy, but everything I’ve read says you don’t have to do that with WCF…which is why I’m attempting this.

**So my questions are…**

- Q: Is it possible to tell WCF to NOT TO IGNORE
  the name-spacing?
- Q: Am I missing a tag? Don’t the WCF
  tags (below) take name-spacing into
  account?
- Q: Do I HAVE to flatten my object
  hierarchy?

**The basic error is…**

> Type
>   'wcfFISH.StateManagement.Contractor.New'
>   cannot be added to list of known types
>   since another type
>   'wcfFISH.StateManagement.CostDivision.New'
>   with the same data contract name
>   'wcfFISH.StateManagement.Contractor:New'
>   is already present.

**The error looks like…**

```
An ExceptionDetail, likely created by IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults=true, whose value is:
System.InvalidOperationException: An exception was thrown in a call to a WSDL export extension: System.ServiceModel.Description.DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior
 contract: http://tempuri.org/:IFishData ----> System.InvalidOperationException: Type 'wcfFISH.StateManagement.Contractor.New' cannot be added to list of known types since another type 'wcfFISH.StateManagement.CostDivision.New' with the same data contract name 'wcfFISH.StateManagement.Contractor:New' is already present.
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.CheckAndAdd(Type type, Dictionary`2 typesChecked, Dictionary`2& nameToDataContractTable)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.ImportKnownTypeAttributes(Type type, Dictionary`2 typesChecked, Dictionary`2& knownDataContracts)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.ImportKnownTypeAttributes(Type type)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.ClassDataContractCriticalHelper.get_KnownDataContracts()
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.get_KnownDataContracts()
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSet.AddClassDataContract(ClassDataContract classDataContract)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSet.Add(XmlQualifiedName name, DataContract dataContract)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSet.AddClassDataContract(ClassDataContract classDataContract)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSet.Add(XmlQualifiedName name, DataContract dataContract)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSet.Add(Type type)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XsdDataContractExporter.Export(Type type)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.MessageContractExporter.ExportType(Type type, String partName, String operationName, XmlSchemaType& xsdType)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.DataContractSerializerMessageContractExporter.ExportBody(Int32 messageIndex, Object state)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.MessageContractExporter.ExportMessage(Int32 messageIndex, Object state)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.MessageContractExporter.ExportMessageContract()
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior.System.ServiceModel.Description.IWsdlExportExtension.ExportContract(WsdlExporter exporter, WsdlContractConversionContext contractContext)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.WsdlExporter.CallExtension(WsdlContractConversionContext contractContext, IWsdlExportExtension extension)
   --- End of inner ExceptionDetail stack trace ---
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.WsdlExporter.CallExtension(WsdlContractConversionContext contractContext, IWsdlExportExtension extension)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.WsdlExporter.CallExportContract(WsdlContractConversionContext contractContext)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.WsdlExporter.ExportContract(ContractDescription contract)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.WsdlExporter.ExportEndpoint(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, XmlQualifiedName wsdlServiceQName)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.WsdlExporter.ExportEndpoints(IEnumerable`1 endpoints, XmlQualifiedName wsdlServiceQName)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataBehavior.MetadataExtensionInitializer.GenerateMetadata()
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataExtension.EnsureInitialized()
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataExtension.HttpGetImpl.InitializationData.InitializeFrom(ServiceMetadataExtension extension)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataExtension.HttpGetImpl.GetInitData()
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataExtension.HttpGetImpl.TryHandleDocumentationRequest(Message httpGetRequest, String[] queries, Message& replyMessage)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataExtension.HttpGetImpl.ProcessHttpRequest(Message httpGetRequest)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataExtension.HttpGetImpl.Get(Message message)
   at SyncInvokeGet(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage4(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage3(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage2(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage1(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)
```

**The service code looks like…**

```
namespace wcfFISH.StateManagement
{
    [DataContract(Namespace = "wcfFISH.StateManagement")]
    [KnownType(typeof(wcfFISH.StateManagement.C1FE.Approved))]
    [KnownType(typeof(wcfFISH.StateManagement.C1FE.Denied))]
    [KnownType(typeof(wcfFISH.StateManagement.C1FE.New))]
    [KnownType(typeof(wcfFISH.StateManagement.C1FE.Pending))]
    [KnownType(typeof(wcfFISH.StateManagement.Contractor.Authenticated))]
    [KnownType(typeof(wcfFISH.StateManagement.Contractor.New))]
    [KnownType(typeof(wcfFISH.StateManagement.CostDivision.Authenticated))]
    [KnownType(typeof(wcfFISH.StateManagement.CostDivision.New))]
    [KnownType(typeof(wcfFISH.StateManagement.ReportingPeriod.Closed))]
    [KnownType(typeof(wcfFISH.StateManagement.ReportingPeriod.Open))]
    public abstract class ObjectState
    {
        #region CONSTRUCTORS

        protected ObjectState()
        { }

        #endregion

        #region PROPERTIES & FIELDS

        #endregion

        #region EVENTS
        #endregion

        #region METHODS    
        #endregion
    }
}
```

**Side note…**

Another reason I am confused is the original declarations listed below NEVER caused an issue...and it was working fine!  This only happened when I ADDED CostDivision!

```
[KnownType(typeof(wcfFISH.StateManagement.C1FE.New))]
[KnownType(typeof(wcfFISH.StateManagement.Contractor.New))]
```

**In case I’m not being clear…**

My understanding is WCF should understand the difference between the following classes:

```
[KnownType(typeof(wcfFISH.StateManagement.Contractor.Authenticated))]
[KnownType(typeof(wcfFISH.StateManagement.Contractor.New))]
[KnownType(typeof(wcfFISH.StateManagement.CostDivision.Authenticated))]
[KnownType(typeof(wcfFISH.StateManagement.CostDivision.New))]
```

**If it does NOT understand…**

I guess my only option seems to be to flatten the hierarchy FOR EVERYTHING to:

```
wcfFISH.StateManagement.Authenticated
wcfFISH.StateManagement.New
```

…is this my only option? (hope not!)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My psychic powers tell me that your declaration of wcfFISH.StateManagement.CostDivision.New was copy/pasted from wcfFISH.StateManagement.Contractor.New and while you changed the class name you didn't change the DataContract attribute on it to match.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.  Let's hear it for psychic powers!  8 )

Comment: now; if only we didnt use auto generate tools for xsd's, this would actually be good advice.